# Create pagination using KnexJS + PG

Tags: node.js, pagination

What would be the most optimal way to create pagination using knexjs? I sincerily have no idea how to do pagination in general. Below my code:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  db.select("*")
    .from("site.site_product")
    .offset(0)
    .limit(10)
    .then(data => {
      res.render("inventory/site_product", { data: data });
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try This

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var reqData = req.query;
    var pagination = {};
    var per_page = reqData.per_page || 10;
    var page = reqData.current_page || 1;
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    var offset = (page - 1) * per_page;
    return Promise.all([
        db.count('* as count').from("site.site_product").first(),
        db.select("*").from("site.site_product").offset(offset).limit(per_page)
    ]).then(([total, rows]) => {
        var count = total.count;
        var rows = rows;
        pagination.total = count;
        pagination.per_page = per_page;
        pagination.offset = offset;
        pagination.to = offset + rows.length;
        pagination.last_page = Math.ceil(count / per_page);
        pagination.current_page = page;
        pagination.from = offset;
        pagination.data = rows;
        res.render("inventory/site_product", {
            data: pagination
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I use [knex-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex-paginate) which makes PG pagination a breeze.

Here are the steps to try it out:

1. `npm install knex-paginate -s`
2. In your knex configuration file, add the following two lines of code:

```
const { attachPaginate } = require('knex-paginate');
attachPaginate();
```

3. Create a route:

```
router.get("/paginated-results", (req, res) => {
  const page = req.query.page;

  return knex("artists").paginate({
    perPage: 10,
    currentPage: page
  }).then(results => {
    res.json(results)
  })
})
```

4. Test it out in postman. The path should look something like: `http://localhost:5000/paginated-results?page=2`